# How to break pages in html with tables

Tags: html, css

I am printing my page with jQuery. Now I want to print each table on new page e.g (Page 1-->Table 1,Page 2-->Table 2) with page break. but page break is not working.
My tables are as follows:

table 1

```
<table class="col-md-12">contents</table>
```

table 2

```
 <table class="col-md-12">contents</table>
```

table 3

```
<table class="col-md-12">contents</table>
```

My Css

```
 @media print {table {
    page-break-after: always;
}
```

}

Comment: can you show some code ?

Comment: you'll need to include the code you're using for others to help

Answer (score 0):

You can use some thing like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
    table { page-break-inside:auto }
    tr    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
    thead { display:table-header-group }
    tfoot { display:table-footer-group }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr><th>heading</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr><td>notes</td></tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>x</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>x</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>x</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```